# While loop showing all data

Tags: php, loops

I've been trying to make a php script echo all the data in mysqli procedural..
I've searched online but all i find is how to output arrays one by one using object oriented style and I cannot use the fetch_all function as my host's php version is under 5.3. I would like to know how to make a while loop go through the database and echo all usernames and the corresponding pendingpoints that are over '0'.

**EDIT:** Made a mistake with the 'over 20' I actually mean 0

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?
    $submit = $_POST['submit'];
    if ($submit) {

        $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT *                     
                               FROM members WHERE pendingpoints > 0    
                               ");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,             
                                  MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["username"],         
            $row["pendingpoints"]);
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your query to

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE pendingpoints > 0
```

then,

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
     echo $row['username'].' '.$row['pendingpoints'];
}
```

also make sure you are including your database connection file.

Comment: I used this but it only gives me 1 row of 1 user with his pendingpoints, but I want to see a list with every user that has more than 0 pendingpoints

Comment: oh just saw your edit.  change the 20 to a 0 then, and this will show every single user.  Make sure your database actually has more than one user with more than 0 pendingpoints

Comment: ^, if that doesn't work, try removing the WHERE statement for debugging. This should print out your entire database's usernames and points.

Comment: Hmmm that's odd. It seems to skip over my first user which has 20 pendingpoints but it works for the rest of users

Comment: hmmm. weird.  this is weird but go into PHPmyadmin and re-enter the value 20.  Just to make sure

Answer (score -1):

Your current MySQL statement finds 'pendingpoints' above 0. You want 20, not 0.

Comment: Little misake, I meant over 0

Comment: This post should be a comment, not an answer.  Please remove.  The question is fixed now anyhow.